# Not able to see converted Excel to HTML through Django

Tags: python, html, django, render, display

I have converted on Excel(with 2 tabs) to HTML. Now I want to display this generated HTML on a webpage with Django code. But I am not able to get the entire data in my webpage.

Following is my Django code.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def download_y9cfile1(request, file_name):  
filePath = CommonUtils.get_absolute_file_path('app','static','generated','HTML', file_name)       
logger.debug("File name is %s" % filePath )
try:
    relevantFile = open(filePath,'rb')
    response = HttpResponse((relevantFile), content_type='text/html')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="%s"' %file_name
except IOError:
    logger.exception("File doesn't exist")
    return HttpResponse("File doesn't exist", status=500)
    return response
```

I think the issue is that Django is not able to read the supporting CSS file for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the file contents to `HttpResponse` instead of the file handle:

```
response = HttpResponse(relevantFile.read(), content_type='text/html')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using this. But the problem now is as the Excel was having 2 TABS. and the converted HTML has CSS files as well. So the django code is not able to get the required CSS from the folder.

Thats why onl some data is getting populated as the django code is not able to get the required CSS for display.

Please let me know if you have nay views on the same.

Comment: That sounds lie a separate issue. You either need to make a separate view to serve the CSS, or you can include the CSS in the HTML file itself.

Comment: For the second option i.e. include the CSS in the HTML file itself. we have .mht file (where when excel converted to html will have both html and css code). But the problem with this is that we cannot handle .mht files with angular JS Iframes. So it will be difficult to display it .

For the first option for to create a seperate view for handling the CSS, I am not sure how can I do the same. Please tell me if you have done something like that before.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, all I noticed was that you were missing `.read()` when you returned your response. Hope you figure it out.